# Hide deleted mails in alpine

Tags: linux, email, alpine-mail

The mail server I've been using for the last few years had a reasonable web interface that was shutdown last week. This forced me to essentially switch to using ssh+alpine.

All in all, I found the transition to be smooth (with the annoying exception that my entire address book is gone). But one thing bothers me.

In the webmail interface, I could mark an email as "deleted" and then choose "hide/unhide deleted emails". I do this because I don't like to expunge deleted emails all too often. But at the same time, I want to slightly declutter my inbox.

> Is there a way to just hide mails marked as deleted on alpine?

(For concreteness, I'm using alpine 2.10, if that matters.)